# Java Number Pattern Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a lab for a class where a user inputs a number and it recursively prints out a number pattern. For example,

The base case is if they enter 1, it will print: `1`

If they enter 2 it will print: `1 2 1`

If 3, it will print: `1 2 1 3 1 2 1`

and then for something bigger, if they enter 7, it will print:

```
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 7
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
```

I'm a little stuck on what the number pattern is to be able to complete this problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If it isn't defined in the homework, it becomes a sort of guessing game (instead of a programming problem).  It certainly looks like you can join the number with the results of the previous number to the left and right, but who knows...

Answer (score 1):

So you need to write a recursive function. Something of this form:

```
private String pattern(int num) {
    // ...
}
```

The most important part is finding the right exit condition that should stop the recursion. In this case, that's when `num == 1`.

From the description, it looks like for a number `k`,
the output is `pattern(k - 1) + k + pattern(k - 1)`.

I already spoiled too much.
You might need to improve the efficiency of this.
For example, realize that you don't need to run `pattern(k - 1)` twice,
it's enough to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a little stuck on what the number pattern is to be able to
>   complete this problem.

Lets try to analyse the sequence using some function f
f(1) = 1     (Total digits = **1**) 
f(2) = 1 2 1 ( Total digits = **3**) 
f(3) = 121 3 121 (Total digits = **7**) 
f(4) = 1213121 4 1213121 (Total digits = **15**)
f(5) = 121312141213121 5 121312141213121 (Total digits = **31**)

So as you can observe total digits sequence looks like 1,3,7,15,31,....2^n-1 
Now we can express this logic as mentioned below(Note : in order to help you to better understand how the program works i am printing sequence at every level)

```
public class SequenceGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generate(7);
    }

    static void generate(int depth) {
        recursiveGenerator(1, null, depth);
    }

    static void recursiveGenerator(int num, String prev, int limit) {
        if (num <= limit) {
            if (prev != null) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (prev != null) {
                System.out.printf("%s %d %s", prev, num, prev);

            } else {
                prev = "";
                System.out.printf("%d", num);
            }
            if (prev.equals("")) {
                prev += num + prev;
            } else {
                prev += " " + num + " " + prev;
            }
            recursiveGenerator(++num, prev, limit);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
1
1 2 1
1 2 1 3 1 2 1
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 7 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
```